# How would I get the index of the first non-whitespace character in a string?

Tags: java

In java, how would I find the index of the first non-whitespace character in a string after the first occurring whitespace?  For example, say I had the string:

```
String mystring = "one two three"
```

I want some sort of method that will return the value: 4
Since the character "t" is in the first character after the first white space.

Comment: Are you going to have more than one white space between words?  That changes the solution to the problem a bit.

Comment: You will write some code to do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, and output 4

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(final String... args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\s]+)?(\\s)+");
    String mystring = "one two three";
    final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(mystring);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.end());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function for this. However it is quite simple to write a function that does this:

```
public static int getIndexOfNonWhitespaceAfterWhitespace(String string){
    char[] characters = string.toCharArray();
    boolean lastWhitespace = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isWhitespace(characters[i])){
            lastWhitespace = true;
        } else if(lastWhitespace){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```